# tracking mysql changes in the long term -- for formation of line graphs etc

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table I manage for a competition I run, currently it has 4 columns.

```
ID
Name
Tag
Rating
```

Effectively, I want to track the changes of the tag (and the dates that it changes) for as long as possible to provide my users a line graph of their play in the competition.

I've tried looking around for a way of doing it, but most that I could find with my limited knowledge is ways to only save the last change, or ways to save the whole table when a change is made. In my case the changes are to individual users (rows), so they would need to be tracked individually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit:

sample

```
id | name        | tag   |  rating 
-------------------------
 1 | Khar        | 5     | 800
 2 | SantaCruz   | 3     | 850
 3 | Sion        | 2     | 900
 4 | VT          | 1     | 758
 5 | newFort     | 4     | 535
 6 | Bandra      | 6     | 483
 7 | Worli       | 10    | 888
 8 | Sanpada     | 11    | 999
 9 | Joe         | 9     | 779
10 | Sally       | 15    | 888
11 | Elphiston   | 17    | 525
12 | Currey Road | 31    | 879
```

the tag is effectively the ranking that I want to track in a longer term.

When it comes to the desired outcome, I am not sure what is possible. Effectively I would want to be able to create a line graph for every individual, (y axis: tag, x axis: dates) so another table which tracks all the changes and their dates I guess would be ideal.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: added. I hope it is clear enough

Comment: Your data is incomplete.  You don't have a date column in the data.  And MySQL does not produce line graphs.  Are you asking something about the data, about a query, or how to make line graphs?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the calculated tag values in a separate table `ttbl` (you never change any values but instead always `insert` them there!):

```
tid  |  uid |  tag | changed
------------------------------------------
  1  |    1 |   5  | '2017-09-24T15:34:23'
  2  |    1 |   8  | '2017-09-24T15:36:23'
  3  |    2 |   3  | '2017-09-24T15:38:23'
  4  |    3 |   2  | '2017-09-24T15:40:23'
  5  |    4 |   1  | '2017-09-24T16:34:23'
  6  |    5 |   4  | '2017-09-24T16:44:23'
  7  |    1 |   5  | '2017-09-24T18:14:23'
  8  |    6 |   6  | '2017-09-24T18:24:23'
  9  |    1 |   9  | '2017-09-24T18:34:23'
 10  |    7 |   10 | '2017-09-24T18:44:23'
 11  |    1 |   5  | '2017-09-25T15:31:23'
 12  |    8 |   11 | '2017-09-25T15:32:23'
 13  |    9 |   9  | '2017-09-25T15:33:23'
 14  |   10 |   15 | '2017-09-25T15:34:23'
 15  |   11 |   17 | '2017-09-25T15:35:23'
 16  |   12 |   31 | '2017-09-25T15:36:23'
```

Note, that the tag value for uid=1 changes from 5 to 8, 5, 9 and back to 5 again over time.

Now, with a special select you fish out the *latest values for a specific cut-off point in time* like this:

```
SELECT t.* FROM ttbl t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT uid i, max(changed) dt 
            FROM ttbl WHERE changed<'20170925'
            GROUP BY uid) u ON i=uid AND dt=changed;
```

The date value `'20170925'` here represents the cut-off time. Feel free to join this to your table with the current rating values or other stuff.

You can find a little demo here: http://rextester.com/GZNL52987

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`trigger`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) to store ranking values inside another table.

I would define the new table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_history` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` int(8) NOT NULL, -- 8 seems to be enough for your needs
  `player` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

ALTER TABLE `tag_history` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `tag_history` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Using this trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE ON `my_table_name`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.tag <> OLD.tag THEN
        INSERT INTO `tag_history` (tag, player) VALUES (NEW.tag, NEW.name);
    END IF;
END;
```

Having `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value for `timestamp` will automatically store the date and time of your `UPDATE` inside the row.

Or, because you tagged this question PHP, you can simply `INSERT INTO tag_history` when updating your table within your PHP script, without having to use any trigger.

But this means you will have to store future updates to your table before being able to draw any graph as you don't have a timestamp for your entries.